# Spark Memory Allocation

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have the Yarn cluster with below configuration. I am using spark for my operations across clusters. There will be maximun of five concurrent spark jobs that may run at any point of time. Currently the spark jobs are executing with dynamic allocation true property which sometimes causing other jobs to wait for resources. I want to fixed the resources allocation for each job to use only 20% of cluster resources. Can someone help me in solving this.

Master node:
RAM: 125G
Cores:32

Total No of worker nodes: 45
Allocated RAM: 24GB per each node (total 1080GB of RAM)
Allocated Cores: 8 cores per each node(total 360 cores)

I tried multiple memory configuration but still it using incorrect memory/cores.

Comment: If the allocation is dynamic, how is it "incorrect"? It's not going to use 100% of the cluster if it doesn't need to

Answer (score 0):

> I want to fixed the resources allocation for each job to use only 20% of cluster

You can set the `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors` which default is infinity, to a value matching 20% of the total resources.

For example, if you have a total of 100 cores, you could create executors with 5 cores each, then you would set the maximum to 4. As a result you would never go beyong 20% of your cluster per job.

More about dynamic configuration here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation